How to Synchronizing Data Extraction with Asynchronous Page Navigation | Puppeteer
Lets say I have a page which scrap data for table rows and each row has a button which open new page(like an image viewer) to get the image url using nodejs and puppeteer.
After clicking the button in each row to open the detailed page, I am encountering issues with asynchronous behavior. Specifically, the event listener for new page creation is triggering multiple times, but it seems the promises are resolving with the image URL of the last row for all rows, instead of each row's corresponding image URL.
It gets the url of the last row and sets their url as well...
const tableRows = await page.$$('#DocList1_ContentContainer1 .DataGridRow, .DataGridAlternatingRow');
let extractedData;
const pagePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  browser.on('targetcreated', async (target) => {
    if (target.type() === 'page') {
      try {
        const page = await target.page();
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)); //added settimeout for imageloading

        await page.close()
        resolve(await page.evaluate(() => {
          return document.querySelector('img#ImageViewer1_docImage')?.src || "";
        }));`your text``your text`
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error in target page => ", error)
      }
    }
  });
});
const rowPromises = tableRows.map(async (rowHandle) => {
  await rowHandle.$eval('.cssButtonImgSmall16.cssBasketImgButton', button => button.click());
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));

  const fileDatePromise = rowHandle.$eval('td:nth-child(2)', node => node.textContent.trim());
  const bookPagePromise = rowHandle.$eval('td:nth-child(3)', node => node.textContent.trim());

  console.log('click event');
  const [fileDate, bookVolPage, imageUrl] = await Promise.all([fileDatePromise, bookVolPagePromise, pagePromise]);
  return { fileDate, bookVolPage, imageUrl };
});

extractedData = await Promise.all(rowPromises);

return extractedData;



would it be possible that you provide a public url, so that we can reproduce the issue to better understand it, please?
